# cocos2d-x creating a CCMenuItem error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm starting to learn cocos2d-x and I have a weird error while creating a CCMenuItem Here is my code

```
CCMenuItem *StartMenuItem = CCMenuItemImage::create("startbutton.png", "startbutton.png", this, callfunc_selector(tutButtonTapped()));
CCMenuItem *TutMenuItem = CCMenuItemImage::create("startbutton.png", "startbutton.png", this, callfunc_selector(tutButtonTapped()));
```

and I'm receiving this error:

```
Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
```

On both lines... Its pointing on the selector but I have no idea what to do...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to omit the brackets and prefix the selector method with the class name.

```
callfunc_selector(YourClass::tutButtonTapped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write code in (HelloWorld.h)

```
{
  cocos2d::Menu *menu1;
  cocos2d::MenuItemImage *Back;
  void OnBack(cocos2d::Ref *pSender);
}
```

Write code in init Method(HelloWorld.cpp)

```
{
   Back = MenuItemImage::create("ImgBack.png","ImgBack.png",CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::OnBack,this));
Back->setScale(1.0);

 Back->setPosition(Point(670,950));
 menu1=cocos2d::Menu::create(Back, NULL);
 menu1->setPosition(0,0);
 this->addChild(menu1);
}
```

// Create Separate method Press Back Button it Call.

```
void HelloWorld::OnBack(Ref *pSender)
{

}
```